# UIScrollview resetting contentsize

Tags: objective-c, uiscrollview

I have a `UIScrollview` that contains data for a default height of 1717px, on runtime I have to add one or more subviews who are each 540px in height. It is unknown beforehand how many of them will have to be added.

I add these to the scrollview in the `viewdidload` method and then set the `contentsize` to the correct values. I also set the contentsize to whatever value I need it to be. If I log it at the end of the method all is well and the `contentsize` is still correct.

Once it is displayed the `contentsize` has reverted back to 1717px, the content is still there though. I can view the added content for a second if I scroll beyond the normal range of the `uiscrollview`, but it then bounces back.

The relevant part of my `viewdidload` is below

```
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"counter" ascending:YES]];
for (Facade * f in [self.inspection.facades sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors]) {
    NSArray *subviewArray = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"facadeView" owner:self options:nil];
    facadeView *facadeInfo = [subviewArray objectAtIndex:0];
    facadeInfo.facade = f;
    facadeInfo.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.scrollView.frame.size.height, facadeInfo.frame.size.width, facadeInfo.frame.size.height);
    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.scrollView.frame.size.width, self.scrollView.frame.size.height+facadeInfo.frame.size.height);
    self.scrollView.frame =  CGRectMake(0, 0, self.scrollView.frame.size.width, self.scrollView.frame.size.height+facadeInfo.frame.size.height);
    [self.scrollView addSubview:facadeInfo];
}
self.scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);;
// now add our scroll view to the main view
[self.view addSubview:self.scrollView];
```

What can I do to stop my `contentsize` from resetting to the original values?

Answer (score 1):

try this code in `viewDidAppear` instead of `viewDidLoad` .

Answer (score 0):

I think

`self.scrollView.frame =  CGRectMake(0, 0, self.scrollView.frame.size.width, self.scrollView.frame.size.height+facadeInfo.frame.size.height);`

inside the for loop is the problem. you don't need to increase the frame size. if you do so you cant scroll. contentsize must be smaller then frame size. if not so scroll view can't be scroll.

Comment: The size of the scrollview is fine, it gets changed back to the correct value after the loop. it is mostly used to keep track of the size that the contentsize has to be in the next iteration of the loop. I could change the code there to not use the framesize for calculating my contentsize, but didn't see the option when I was writing that code.

Answer (score -1):

It is a problem with autoLayout. Disable auto layout and it will work fine!!!:-)